# dropdownlist if else get pk in controller or form in yii

Tags: php, yii

newbie here. 
I am not sure what's the best way to do this. I would like to create a new record if 'not listed' is selected, and get pk if the user selects from the list.

I am not sure if i would write something in controller or in my form or elsewhere? and how would i do this?

In my form I have:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'store_name', CHtml::listData($model->findAll(),'store_id','store_name'),array('prompt'=>'Not Listed'));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller.

```
if($model->store_name === null && $_POST['new_store_name'] !== null){
   $search = StoreTable::model()->findbyattributes(array('store_name' => $_POST['new_store_name']));
   if(!$search){
      $create = new StoreTable();
      $create->store_name = $_POST['new_store_name'];
      $create->save();

      $model->store_name = $create->id;
   }
   else {
      $model->store_name = $search->id;
   }
}

$model->save();
```